# How long is to long to wait to accept an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I asked a question and it may be a while before I make the recipe again to test out the answer. There are also multiple answers that need testing to find the best one.

How long is it acceptable to leave a question open without an accepted answer? Should I accept the answer with the most votes before I am able to try them out to get the question answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meta Stack Exchange has a longish [Q/A on accepting answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), you may want to use this as a starting point.

That said, we see lots of questions that never get accepted, often asked by one-time users (sometimes jokingly called drive-by posters) that never bothered to learn about how the site works etc. So: Thanks for your effort and your question here! Questions without accepted answers may pop up again due to how the system works in the background, but yours wouldn’t be the only one. I believe accepting an answer at some point is important - it signals the user base that the asker was satisfied - but there’s no need to rush. Our sister site English Language Learners even [discourages super fast accepts](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).

In short, accept when you feel you are ready and you have your best answer. This may or may not be the one with the highest votes and remember that you can always change the accepted answer, that’s entirely up to you.

Comment: I will remember to come back and accept an answer as soon as I am able to try them out. :)